# RecyclerView performance with SQLLite, imageViews and recyclable = false

Tags: android, performance, sqlite, android-recyclerview, android-sqlite

A performance question here. I have a recyclerView (in a fragment) that I'm populating from a database that's going to eventually hold around 16,000 items in a single table, 18 columns per record, nothing trickier than ints, decimals and varchars and the records are categorized so I don't expect to ever need loading more than, say, 300 at a time. Should I consider limiting the selects or implementing some sort of paging? I'd prefer to keep the recyclerView simple and seamlessly scrolling.

I'm also wondering about the recyclerView itself. The rows are rather complex and have two states: the default collapsed state shows 6 views including a single imageView, and upon clicking a row we get expanded state (a container goes from GONE to VISIBLE) with a total of 21 views including 2 imageViews. I care about the quality of imageViews so I'm testing it with a resolution limited at 512px for a small image (50% screen width) and 1024px for a large image (100% screen width), everything in JPGs. And because I need to track the state of rows, I have used

`holder.setIsRecyclable(false);`

in my onBindViewHolder in the recyclerViewAdapter, because without it expanding one row results in some of the following, recycled rows being expanded too. And I obviously want to have every row collapsed until explicitly expanded by user. So the thing is, the recyclerView doesn't scroll so smoothly, there is a noticeable scrolling lag as new rows enter the screen and the old rows leave it, or vice versa. When tested on a reasonably powerful device (LG G7 Fit) the experience is, frankly, quite jumpy. What can I do to optimize the performance (yes, I'm using 6 various sizes of images for various resolutions already). Is there perhaps a better alternative to the recyclerView that wouldn't need turning everything upside down?

Answer (score 0):

FYI after an extensive testing I found that the most drastic improvement to the smoothness of scrolling is gained by reducing resolution of the images in the first (always visible) imageView.